# Effectively retrieving object with nested collections using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I am creating a survey application where I have a survey which has a collection of pages. Each page will have a collection of questions and each question will have a collection of answer options. My class structure looks like:

```
public class Survey : Entity {
    public IList<Page> Pages { get; set; }
}

public class Page : Entity {
    public IList<Question> Questions { get;set; }
}

public class Question : Entity {
    public IList<Option> Options { get; set; }
}

public class Option : Entity {}
```

The mapping for each class is:

```
<!-- mapping for ID and other properties excluded -->
<class name="Survey">
    <bag name="Pages" generic="true" inverse="true">
        <key column="SurveyId" />
        <one-to-many class="Page" />
    </bag>
    <bag name="Questions" access="none">
        <key column="SurveyId" />
        <one-to-many class="Question" />
    </bag>
</class>

<class name="Page">
    <many-to-one name="Survey" column="SurveyId" />
    <bag name="Questions" generic="true" inverse="true">
        <key column="PageId" />
        <one-to-many class="Question" />
    </bag>
</class>

<class name="Question">
    <many-to-one name="Page" column="PageId" />
    <many-to-one name="Survey" column="SurveyId" />
    <bag name="Options" generic="true" inverse="true">
        <key column="QuestionId" />
        <one-to-many class="Option" />
    </bag>
</class>

<class name="AnswerOption">
    <many-to-one name="Question" column="QuestionId" />
</class>
```

I need to display all the questions on a page so I start with the survey object and loop through the pages, items and options. This causes NHibernate to execute many queries and I would like to optimize this. How can I get the survey object with the nested collections in the best possible way without executing too many queries?

This is the code I have at the moment but it still executes many queries:

```
var result = Session.CreateMultiQuery()
    .Add(Session.CreateQuery("from Survey s inner join fetch s.Pages where s.Id = :id"))
    .Add(Session.CreateQuery("from Survey s inner join fetch s.Question where s.Id = :id"))
    .SetInt32("id", id)
    .List();

IList list = (IList)result[0];
return list[0] as Survey;
```

I have also tried Future queries but they don't help to reduce the number of queries.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you can achieve this with the following HQL (of course the same idea can be used with ICriteria)

```
from Survey s
  inner join fetch s.Pages p
  inner join fetch p.Questions q
  inner join fetch q.Options
where s.Id = :id
```

If you also want to fetch `survey.Questions` then the best option is to fetch those in separate qyery and used Futures to avoid cartesian product.

Also, if I remember correctly HQL queries ignores fetch's defined in mappings. If the collection is mapped with `lazy="false" fetch="join"` then it is fetch when used ICriteria but not when using HQL.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding

```
lazy="false" fetch="join"
```

to your bag declarations. That way you can be sure the bag will be fetched using one query.

Comment: I had added lazy="false" to my mapping without fetch and that did not help. Adding fetch reduced the queries. However, I do not want to change the mapping as I would be fetching just a question or just the survey object and don't need the collections. Can this be done using HQL or Criteria API?

Answer (score 0):

A solution I'm using is reversing relation between entities. With this you can be sure when a record of `Survey` is loaded, no record of `Page` is loaded unless you call `LoadAll` method. LoadAll is a method in each class that search all related records. Consider following code:

```
public class Survey : Entity {
Survey[] LoadAll {
string hql = "from Page page where page.SurveyID =" + this.ID;
//....
}
}

public class Page : Entity {
    public Survey { get;set; }
}

public class Question : Entity {
    public Page Page { get; set; }
}

public class Option : Entity {
    public Question Question {set; get;}
}
```

Comment: Correct. I have a LoadAll method but not in the Survey class. What I want to know is if there is a way to write HQL (or Criteria) to load the survey, all the pages, all questions in each page and all answer options for each question in the most efficient way.

Comment: If I were using SQL, I would use a `select distinct` on `Options`.